# Быстрая сортировка. Как выбрать случайный опорный элемент списка? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Хочу сделать опорным элементом случайный элемент массива, а не нулевой.

```
import random

my_Arr=[5,6,2,3,56,78,0,5,4,-4]
def quick_sort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    else:
        # pivot=array[random.randint(0,(len(array)-1))] <—хочу, чтобы опорный элемент выбирался случайно
        pivot=array[0]
        less_pivot=[i for i in array[1:0] if i <= pivot]
        greater_pivot=[i for i in array[1:0] if i > pivot]
        return quick_sort(less_pivot) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater_pivot)
print(quick_sort(my_Arr))
```

Comment: `random.choice(array)` не подойдёт? https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice Ещё Вы не сказали, в чём конкретно проблема

Comment: Как определить массивы less_pivot и greater_pivot в этом случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с минимальными изменениями:

```
import random

my_Arr=[5,6,2,3,56,78,0,5,4,-4]

def quick_sort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    else:
        pivotidx = random.randint(0,(len(array)-1))
        array[0], array[pivotidx] = array[pivotidx], array[0]
        pivot = array[0]
        less_pivot=[i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot]
        greater_pivot=[i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot]
        return quick_sort(less_pivot) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater_pivot)

print(quick_sort(my_Arr))

[-4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 56, 78]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Но зачем эта строка    array[0], array[pivotidx] = array[pivotidx], array[0]    ?

Comment: Это обмен случайного элемента с нулевым, чтобы разделитель стоял в начале и не участвовал в разделении